# Link to another page with anchor div id

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a number of dropdown links on my main navigation that need to link to other landing pages and scroll or show specific part of that page, like an article or a specific service. I have went through a lot of examples here but can't get this to work:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="location.href = '/voice-data#broadband/'">BROADBAND & MANAGED INTERNET</a>
```

The above link should anchor to this div on another page:

```
<div class="row broadband-block" id="#broadband">
```

At the moment it lands on the page it needs but doesn't go to the anchor div that it's supposed to,but it does add #broadband to the url in the browser. What am I doing wrong and what would be the best solution, as I have quite a few links like that to do?

Comment: why use javascript to do what a link will do normally, all you are doing with the above is reducing accessibility

Comment: Your `<div>` "id" value should be "broadband", not "#broadband". And you can put the URL directly in the "href" on the `<a>` tag; there's no need for a click handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should do this

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="/voice-data/#broadband">BROADBAND & MANAGED INTERNET</a>
```

just use the href instead of onclick.

and the ids should match, at the current state you should be using ##broadband
while you should use the id as follows:

```
<div class="row broadband-block" id="broadband">
```

Edit: @pointy pointed it out (no pun intended)

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out this obvious error, my brain is fried today it seems. Need to double check for typos next time, also thx everyone for suggesting on abandoning js for this.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the ID attribute. Remove the # from your ID and it should fix your problem:

```
<div class="row broadband-block" id="#broadband">
<div class="row broadband-block" id="broadband">
```

Or adjust your 'a' tag and add an extra '#' to the front of your url:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="location.href = '/voice-data##broadband/'">BROADBAND & MANAGED INTERNET</a>
```

Also, javascript onclick not needed unless this is what your application environment requires, it can all be done inside href attribute.